# Filtering numpy arrays based on the index of certain value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter, masking

I have a numpy array like:

```
array([[ 1, 17, 33, ..., 28,  9, 22],
       [ 3, 11,  1, ..., 25, 45, 14],
       [ 3, 11,  1, ..., 21, 23,  5],
       ...,
       [20,  6, 27, ..., 43, 15, 14],
       [27,  6, 39, ..., 37, 17,  2],
       [ 3, 11,  8, ..., 27, 35, 32]], dtype=int32)
```

From here, I would like to filter out rows where value 4 is occurring at index of 10 or before.

e.g.
[1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 34, 35] - filter, as value 4 is occurring at index3, which is before index 10

e.g.
[35, 34, 33, 32..., 4, 3, 2, 1] - keep, as value 4 is occurring after index10.

what would be the way to achieve this filtering using numpy masking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
arr = np.array(
    [[1, 2, 3, 4, 34, 35, 2, 1],
     [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
     [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
     [4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
     [35, 34, 33, 32, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
)

V, T = 4, 3 # <-- change the threshold to 10

m = np.any(arr[:, :T+1] == V, axis=1)

out = arr[~m]
```

Output :

```
print(out)

array([[ 1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [35, 34, 33, 32,  4,  3,  2,  1]])
```

*Intermediates :*

```
>>> arr[:, :T+1]
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  5],
       [ 1,  2,  4,  5],
       [ 4,  2,  3,  5],
       [35, 34, 33, 32]])

>>> arr[:, :T+1] == V
array([[False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False]])

>>> np.any(arr[:, :T+1] == V, axis=1)
array([ True, False,  True,  True, False])
```

Comment: What happens to rows that don't contain 4?

Comment: It think this is the right idea, but a test case like `[4, 0, 2, 3, 4, 34, 35, 2]` is problematic — it seems to get included in the output.

Comment: Maybe not yet because the OP does not tell if the value `4` can occur more than once in a row..

Comment: Oops, that was a bad example. This is what I meant: `[ 4,  0,  2,  3,  5, 34, 35,  2]` when 4 is at index 0 `idx == 0` is True.

Comment: No worries and thank you again ;). IMHO, I think a more robust approach would be to slice the array to keep only the portions before the threshold (*which is* `10` *in OP and* `3` *in my example*) then perform [*boolean array indexing*](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing). I updated the answer with the intermediates as well.

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way to do it, the key bit is `[4 not in i for i in vals[:,:10]]` which creates a mask by iterating through a view of the first 10 elements of each row.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

vals = np.random.choice(50, size=(10, 100))

print(vals[:,:10])
print(vals.shape)
vals = vals[[4 not in i for i in vals[:,:10]]]
print(vals.shape)
print(vals[:,:10])
```

which should yield:

```
[[44 47  0  3  3 39  9 19 21 36]
 [ 5 41 35  0 31  5 30  0 49 36]
 [24 15 41 18 40 15 11 38 47 29]
 [ 2  5 37 12 44  2 47 27 21 39]
 [42 48 30 16 26 35 49 42  9 44]
 [ 3 34 40 33 28  4 26 32 45  9]
 [41 38 43 18  7 28  1 41  2 28]
 [36 49 24 33 18 33 14 49  7 43]
 [ 6 27 35  6 19 34 38 20 43  0]
 [ 9 20 37 48 17  9 44 15 38 14]]
(10, 100)
(9, 100)
[[44 47  0  3  3 39  9 19 21 36]
 [ 5 41 35  0 31  5 30  0 49 36]
 [24 15 41 18 40 15 11 38 47 29]
 [ 2  5 37 12 44  2 47 27 21 39]
 [42 48 30 16 26 35 49 42  9 44]
 [41 38 43 18  7 28  1 41  2 28]
 [36 49 24 33 18 33 14 49  7 43]
 [ 6 27 35  6 19 34 38 20 43  0]
 [ 9 20 37 48 17  9 44 15 38 14]]
```